# Is there a way to use discord.js to get args for Random-puppy to search that subreddit?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am literally brand new to node.js so I need a bit of help.
I don't have any code, except for other commands. I want to make a command called "subsrc" that takes an argument and uses random puppy to search that subreddit. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're referring to when mentioning `Random-puppy`. Is this an NPM package, web service, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random-puppy` npm package. Install it with `npm i random-puppy`. For example:

```
const randomPuppy = require('random-puppy');

randomPuppy(args[0]).then(url => {
    message.channel.send(url);
});
```

Note you have to define `message` variable (your Discord message object) and `args` (an array of the arguments).